# cannot find a class or type named "Cell"

Tags: processing

So I was trying to make a game of life, so before setup I put in

`Cell[][] board;`

to get an array of arrays of cells, and I put this before setup.

I also made a class Cell. Everything else compiled nicely, except for the fact that it doesn't think Cell is a class or type. How do you get it to accept it as a class?

Thanks.

As asked for

```
Cell[][] board;
void setup() {
  size (400, 400);
  board=new Cell[boardRow][boardCol];
  for (int i=0; i<boardRow; i++) {
    for (int e=0; e<boardCol; e++) {
      board.add( p= random(2), 20*e, 20*i);
    }
  }
}
```

and the beginning and constructor for cell

```
class Cell {
  int xPos;
  int yPos;
  private int state;
  public int cellsNear;
  Cell(int newState, int newXPos, int newYPos) {
    state=newState;
    xPos=newXPos;
    yPos=newYPos;
  }
```

That is essentially how I have it structured for the parts that should be relevant.

Comment: Show us the rest of the code please.

Comment: Is `Cell` defined in a separate file?

Comment: I showed more code, and yes Cell is in a different file in the same sketch. I is a .pde.

Comment: There is still a lot of missing code, some variables in the first code are missing like boardRow and "p", and some methods in the Cell class like the add.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, you haven't really provided enough information. We need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing everything related to your problem, but no extra code that has nothing to do with your problem. What line is your error on? What is the exact text of the error?

But using my psychic crystal ball, I would bet that your problem is on this line:

```
board.add( p= random(2), 20*e, 20*i);
```

Your board variable is an array, and it does NOT have an add() method, let alone one that takes 3 arguments. What are you trying to do here?

It looks like you're mixing up the syntax for instantiating a Cell instance:

```
Cell c = new Cell(random(2), 20*e, 20*i);
```

With the syntax for pointing an array index at an instance:

```
board[e][i] = c;
```

But without knowing more about your actual error, all of this is just guesswork.